# Supress an error / prevent them while editing tables

Tags: vba, ms-word

Thank you for your help with my other questions, and the wonderful information on this site.

I am a doctor. I am trying to be more efficient with my clinic notes.

While writing a patient note, I first write the current medications in a table.

**CURRENT MEDICATIONS**

| Medication | Dose | Instruction |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Levecros 500 mg (Levetiracetam 500 mg) | 1 – 0 – 1 | c |
| Lacosam 100 mg (Lacosamide 100 mg) | 1 – 0 – 1 | s |
| Amlodac 10 mg (Amlodipine 10 mg) | 1 – 0 – 1 | o |

While working on the patient, I put a short letter in the 3rd column. (c for continue, s for stop, o for ask your other doctor about it)

I then a short piece of code (working flawlessly) to copy this table and paste 3 identical tables at the very end of the document.

**MEDICATION CHANGES:**

**1. Stop these medications**

| Medication | Dose | Instruction |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Levecros 500 mg (Levetiracetam 500 mg) | 1 – 0 – 1 | c |
| Lacosam 100 mg (Lacosamide 100 mg) | 1 – 0 – 1 | s |
| Amlodac 10 mg (Amlodipine 10 mg) | 1 – 0 – 1 | o |

**2. Take these medications per my instructions**

| Medication | Dose | Instruction |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Levecros 500 mg (Levetiracetam 500 mg) | 1 – 0 – 1 | c |
| Lacosam 100 mg (Lacosamide 100 mg) | 1 – 0 – 1 | s |
| Amlodac 10 mg (Amlodipine 10 mg) | 1 – 0 – 1 | o |

**3. Take other doctor's medications per his/her instructions**

| Medication | Dose | Instruction |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Levecros 500 mg (Levetiracetam 500 mg) | 1 – 0 – 1 | c |
| Lacosam 100 mg (Lacosamide 100 mg) | 1 – 0 – 1 | s |
| Amlodac 10 mg (Amlodipine 10 mg) | 1 – 0 – 1 | o |

I then run this code:

```
    Dim TargetText2 As String
    Dim oRow2 As Row
    
    TargetText2 = "s"
    
    For Each oRow2 In Doc.Tables(ActiveDocument.Tables.Count - 2).Rows
        If oRow2.Cells(3).Range.Text <> TargetText2 & vbCr & Chr(7) Then oRow2.Delete
    Next oRow2
    
    Dim TargetText3 As String
    Dim oRow3 As Row
    
    TargetText3 = "c"
    
    For Each oRow3 In Doc.Tables(ActiveDocument.Tables.Count - 1).Rows
        If oRow3.Cells(3).Range.Text <> TargetText3 & vbCr & Chr(7) Then oRow3.Delete
    Next oRow3
    
    Dim TargetText4 As String
    Dim oRow4 As Row
    
    TargetText4 = ""
    
    For Each oRow4 In Doc.Tables(ActiveDocument.Tables.Count).Rows
        If oRow4.Cells(3).Range.Text <> TargetText4 & vbCr & Chr(7) Then oRow4.Delete
    Next oRow4
```

Which gives me this output:

**1. Stop these medications**

| Medication | Dose | Instruction |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Lacosam 100 mg (Lacosamide 100 mg) | 1 – 0 – 1 | s |

**2. Take these medications per my instructions**

| Medication | Dose | Instruction |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Levecros 500 mg (Levetiracetam 500 mg) | 1 – 0 – 1 | c |

**3. Take other doctor's medications per his/her instructions**

| Medication | Dose | Instruction |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Amlodac 10 mg (Amlodipine 10 mg) | 1 – 0 – 1 | o |

I then have other code that deletes the 3rd column of all tables for a clean look.

```
'Deleting the now-unecessary 3rd column in all 4 tables (and 2nd column in stop medications table)
Dim oTable As Table
For Each oTable In ActiveDocument.Tables
    oTable.Columns(3).Delete
    oTable.PreferredWidthType = wdPreferredWidthPercent
    oTable.PreferredWidth = 97
Next oTable
```

Now, when there is at least one medication in each category, things work flawlessly.

But when there is no medication in any one category, for example:

| Medication | Dose | Instruction |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Levecros 500 mg (Levetiracetam 500 mg) | 1 – 0 – 1 | c |
| Lacosam 100 mg (Lacosamide 100 mg) | 1 – 0 – 1 | s |
| Amlodac 10 mg (Amlodipine 10 mg) | 1 – 0 – 1 | s |

I get a huge error message. "Error 5941 – The requested member does not exist"

I tried adding:

```
Application.DisplayAlerts = False

On Error Resume Next
```

But it doesn't work. I still get the error message!

Any suggestions?

Warm regards,

Dr. Siddharth Kharkar

Comment: Which line is giving you that error?  And it would be useful to include the code you use to copy the first table - no need to make a copy when there are no entries for one of the categories...

Comment: https://drkharkar.com/for-stackexchange/

Thank you for your message. It is not clear which line, the debug option is grayed out. Here is the code I’m using to triplicate the initial table.

For the life of me, I cant figure out how to post the entire code here. Hence posting it as a link.

Comment: You can edit your question using the link below it, and add the code there.

Comment: Are you able to share a (redacted) example of the document you're working with?  That will save me from having to guess the existing layout.

Comment: Thank you very much for your message.

As luck would have had it, I somehow broke the script entirely, so that it's not working. I think the table count is incorrect.

I have uploaded the document here: https://drkharkar.com/wp-content/uploads/Mr.-John-Jones-BEFORE-RUNNING-UPDATE_TABLES_SCRIPT.docx

The relevant Macro is "Update_Med_Tables".

I don't know how this works, but I am happy to compensate someone willing to help me... I think it would be fair on my part to offer some compensation?

Comment: I will try to look later.  If it was something you needed to pay for, this would not be the site for that. Most people helping out here are doing it for the challenge, or just to help out.  Once money comes into the picture you're no longer "doing a good deed"  but more likely "working for cheap" and those have very different feelings associated with them  

Comment: "The relevant Macro is 'Update_Med_Tables'." - looks like you saved your file with no macros though?

Comment: I am really very sorry. Here is the file with the Macros. Thank you very much for your help. I really appreciate it.
https://drkharkar.com/wp-content/uploads/Mr.-John-Jones-07Mar23.docm.zip

Comment: In case you are uncomfortable downloading the zip file, here is the complete VB script as a seperate file: https://drkharkar.com/wp-content/uploads/VB-Script-for-clinic-software.docx

Comment: Also, here is a more succint problem statement: https://drkharkar.com/wp-content/uploads/Clinic-software-problem-statement.docx

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I came up with based on your original post.  It's a different approach from yours. For each "action" (S/C/O) it scans the table for matching rows, then if it finds any it creates a table with that information in the lcoation where the placeholder is.  If it doesn't find any rows it instead puts some text "No medications in this category".

I think this is a cleaner approach than copy/pasting the table and then deleting rows and the last column.

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub CreateTables()
    Dim tblSource As Table, doc As Document
    Dim r As Long, rw As Row, action, el, placeHolder As Range
    Dim col As Collection, tbl As Table
    
    Set doc = ThisDocument
    'find the source table
    Set tblSource = FindNextTable(doc, "CURRENT MEDICATIONS")
    If tblSource Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox "Source table not found!", vbExclamation
        Exit Sub
    End If
    
    For Each action In Array("S", "C", "O") 'loop possible actions
        
        Set placeHolder = TablePlaceHolder(doc, action) 'find the table placeholder
        
        If Not placeHolder Is Nothing Then 'found the placeholder?
            Set col = GetMatchedRows(tblSource, CStr(action), 3)
            If col.Count > 0 Then    'any matched rows?
                Set tbl = doc.Tables.Add(placeHolder, col.Count + 1, 2)
                tbl.Columns(1).Width = 300
                tbl.Columns(2).Width = 100
                tbl.Cell(1, 1).Range.Text = "Medication"
                tbl.Cell(1, 2).Range.Text = "Dose"
                r = 2 'start filling on row 2
                For Each el In col
                    tbl.Cell(r, 1).Range.Text = CellText(el.Cells(1))
                    tbl.Cell(r, 2).Range.Text = CellText(el.Cells(2))
                    r = r + 1
                Next el
            Else
                placeHolder.Text = "No medications in this category"
            End If
        Else
            MsgBox "No placeholder range found for action '" & action & "'"
        End If
    Next action
    
End Sub

'Return a collection of any rows from table `tbl` where the value in column `colNum`
'   matches `txt`
Function GetMatchedRows(tbl As Table, txt As String, colNum As Long) As Collection
    Dim rw As Row, col As Collection
    Set col = New Collection
    For Each rw In tbl.Rows
        'collect the row if it matches the criteria
        If UCase(CellText(rw.Cells(colNum))) = UCase(txt) Then col.Add rw
    Next rw
    Set GetMatchedRows = col
End Function

'get the text from a cell, minus the "end of cell" marker
Function CellText(c As Cell) As String
    CellText = c.Range.Text
    CellText = Left(CellText, Len(CellText) - 2)
End Function

'In document `doc`, looks for the text `txt` and return the first table following that text
Function FindNextTable(doc As Document, txt As String) As Table
    Dim rng As Range
    Set rng = FindFirstRange(doc, txt)
    If Not rng Is Nothing Then
        Set rng = doc.Range(rng.Start, doc.Range.End)
        If rng.Tables.Count > 0 Then Set FindNextTable = rng.Tables(1)
    End If
End Function

'Given a document and an action (S/C/O), find and return the range
'  where the relevant placeholder text is found
Function TablePlaceHolder(doc As Document, action) As Range
    Dim sText As String, rng As Range
    Select Case UCase(action) 'translate S,C,O to the text to be located
        Case "S": sText = "MedsToStop"
        Case "C": sText = "MedsPerMe"
        Case "O": sText = "MedsPerOtherDoctors"
    End Select
    If Len(sText) = 0 Then Exit Function 'action was not recognised
    Set TablePlaceHolder = FindFirstRange(doc, sText)
End Function

'Find and return the first range with text `txt` in document `doc`
Function FindFirstRange(doc As Document, txt As String) As Range
    Dim rng As Range
    For Each rng In doc.StoryRanges
        With rng.Find
            .ClearFormatting
            .Text = txt
            If .Execute() Then
                Set FindFirstRange = rng 'return the found range
                Exit Function 'found what we wanted
            End If
        End With
    Next rng
End Function
```

Comment: Wow, thank you so much. Let me try it out. Rather than number of tables-2, is there any other way I can reference that table? (The preceding text to that table will always be "Current Medications:"

Comment: I tried using a code but I get a series of 3 error messages:<br>
No placeholder range found for action "S", <br>
No placeholder range found for action "C",<br>
No placeholder range found for action "O",

Comment: See updates above

Comment: Hi Tim, Thank you so much for your help. I realized this was a bit beyond my scope, so I have hired someone on upwork to help me out. I do sincerely appreciate your time and effort. Thank you. Siddharth.